# How to use Google Cloud storage to upload image file?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, image-upload, google-cloud-datastore

These couple day I have been trying to upload images to the Google cloud using Java. However, I did found some source codes around but amazingly, none of them come with the handy lib jar files. I am trying to search for the required jar file but still can not found them all. Here, I am asking, does any one have the sample code that I just directly run? The change of the settings is a necessary but definitely not for libs.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [Java Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/)

Howto you will find here: [Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted)